# Can Java and Python coexist in the same app?

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine, integration, google-cloud-datastore

I need to have a Java instance fetching data directly from the Python's instance datastore. I don't know if that's possible at all. Is the datastore transparent/unique, or each instance (if they can indeed coexist) has its separate datastore?
Suming it up: how can a Java app fetch data from the datastore of a Python app, and vice-versa?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [jython](http://www.jython.org/). It's a python implementation written in java. You can call java functions/classes from python that way. That would allow you to run python code in the java instance.

I don't know of anything to do the opposite (run java inside a python process).

Comment: Running Java inside Python isn't crucial though... but Jython could be a tremendous help.

Answer (score 9):

Different versions of an app share a datastore, and AFAIK you can still have a Java version of your app, and Python version, at the same time. It used to be a necessary hack to use features that were implemented in Python but not (yet) in Java, and quite possibly still is.

Of course only one of those versions can be the *default*, but other versions are accessible.

Comment: No need for the AFAIK, you definitely can do this. It's often used as a hack for a variety of things. You can deploy a python version of your app, give it a different version ID. Even though it's not the default, you can access it using a special URL containing the version id.

Comment: @Brian: thanks, I keep finding myself saying "AFAIK" in relation to app engine, because although I have one (1) app on there, I touch it very rarely, and Google keeps surprising me with exciting new stuff that I don't keep up with :-)

Comment: I keep getting surprised by new stuff too, and I work here. You're not alone :P hehe

Comment: So, i managed to get it working by deploying two apps (Java and Python) and accessing one of them through the "real" path.
Java: http://vamostestaristo.appspot.com/   and Python:  http://1b.latest.vamostestaristo.appspot.com/
As long as the Models are consistent, everything should go fine.