# can both Java and Python be used at the same time on App Engine?

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine

For the **same** registered application on App Engine, is it possible to have both Java **and** Python "applications"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Java and Python coexist in the same app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165824/can-java-and-python-coexist-in-the-same-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same need a week ago or so, and found a solution: [Can Java and Python coexist in the same app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165824/can-java-and-python-coexist-in-the-same-app)

EDIT: I accepted the first answer, but it happens that the second answer gave me best results, as i explain on the comments there.

EDIT 2: Well, it might not be exactly the same need, as i only needed to access the same datastore. If you want Java and Python running side-by-side, then i think Jython would be the best solution, as larsmans mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Use py4j to communicate java and python  and you need only secret id or user id to connect with google app engine .But if you need standalone application for both then you will need yaml file and their configuration.

```
from py4j.java_gateway import JavaGateway
gateway = JavaGateway()                        # connect to the JVM
gateway.jvm.java.lang.System.out.println('Hello World!')
```

Alternatively you can use google app engine plugin for eclipse (if you are using) and deploy java project using run->run as-> Google Web Application and integrate python using Jython.
https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/creating_new_webapp?hl=en